# How to generate Line Renderer in AR navigation view?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm building an AR Indoor Navigation app and I have almost got all things working properly, except a straight navigation path in AR view. Currently, only one directional-arrow is rendered in AR view. Line renderer generates the shortest path in 2D and is also used to give rotation to the arrow in AR view. So instead of an arrow, I want to render a straight path(sort of line renderer in AR view). I have tried generating multiple arrows by predicting the future rotations but all of them fall on the single first arrow. How can I render the navigation line itself in AR view?

Current view

[image: Current Arrow view in AR]

2D map with line renderer

[image: 2D image with line renderer]

Expected output (Reference video>> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPLgFA4Hlk4 )

[image: Expected ouput]